# How to switch between multiple instances of same activity in Android

Tags: android

I have a MenuActivity which has buttons to create new WebViewerActivity activities, passing in a URL in the intent. This will result in multiple WebViewerActivities.

If the user clicks a button on the MenuActivity that already has an active WebViewerActivity it should open that activity, otherwise it should create a new instance of WebViewerActivity.

I can create the multiple instances of the WebViewerActivities but how do I store a handle to them so that I can restore them to the front of the stack. Is there an ID property that I can access?

I am not too familiar with the Activity lifecycles so just a general pointer in the right direction would be great.

Thanks

I am only targeting Android 4+

Comment: Do you use fragments or activities?

Comment: Activities. I use fragments elsewhere but don't see how it would apply to this issue. Could you explain?

Comment: First, i need to ask about your navigation system. After you clicked a button on your MenuActivity, you go WebViewerActivity and then you go back to MenuActivity to go another WebViewerActivity. Is that how it works or do you have other kind of navigation?

Comment: Yes that is how it works.

Comment: Then why do you want to keep instances stored and access them lately? You just need one instance and keep changing url, webview already uses caching so on your next loading, it wont make you wait a lot...

Comment: Because if the user enters data on the webpage and does not submit the changes, their work will be lost when the webview loads another URL

Comment: Then you need to keep webview's instance, because you cannot reach what user typed in webview but webview will keep them for you until you release it. So i would say the best way would be using fragments, instead of activity. You may want to consider to change your structure...

Comment: So do you mean that, unlike on iOS, it is not possible to have multiple instances of an activity and keep track of them so that they can be resumed on-demand (via an id or something), without re-loading their webview?

Comment: That almost defines fragments :) But when you use activities, and when you press back, you kill that activity so there is no way to reach that back.